# How to run a python script installed from distutils

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I have a medium sized python command line program that runns well from my source code, and I've created a source distribution file and installed it into the virtual environment using "python setup.py install"

Since this is a pure Python program, and provided that the end users have installed Python, and the required packages, my idea is that i can distribute it through PyPi for all available platforms as a source distribution.

Upon install, I get an 'appname' directory within the virtualenv site-packages directory, and it also runs correctly when I write "python 'pathtovirtualenv'/Lib/sitepackages/'myappname'

But is this the way the end user is supposed to run distutils-distributed programs from the command line.

I fnd a lot of information on how to distribute a program using distutils, but not on how the end user is supposed to launch it after installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already created a `setup.py`, I would recommend looking at the `entry_points`:

```
  entry_points={
      'console_scripts': [
          'scriptname=yourpackage.module:function',
      ],
  },
```

Here, you have a package named `yourpackage`, and a module named `module` in it, and you refer to the function `function`. This function will wrapped by the script called `scriptname`, which will be installed in the users `bin` folder, which is normally in the `$PATH`, so the user can simply type `scriptname` after he installed your package via `pip install`.

To sum up: a user will install the package via `pip install yourpackage` and finally be able to call the `function` in `module` via `script name`.

Here are some docs on this topic:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation
http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html

Comment: Forgot to mention that I develop on Windows, and need to test on windows. Windows doesn't have a standard place to put command line apps (should have?). I guess the approach above will work on linux and osx.

Comment: so it should be <code>script=myapp.__main__.py:main</code>?

Comment: It should work fine. Read some topics on that, I don't have any Windows experience (and I'm not going to change that ; )

Comment: @user29809 without the `.py`, since you're referring to the `__main__` module (just like when you import it).

Comment: Well, I'm also with Python2.7 which doesn't recognize the entry_point options to setup().

Comment: It definitely works with Python 2.7. Your setuptools maybe outdated though…

Answer (score 0):

Well, I eventually figured it out.

Initially, I wanted to just use distutils, I like it when the end user can install it with minimum of extra dependencies. But I have now discovered that setuptools is the better option in my case.

My directory structure looks like this (Subversion):

```
trunk
  |-- appname
  |     |-- __init__.py   # an empty file
  |     |-- __main__.py   # calls appname.main()
  |     |-- appname.py    # contains a main() and imports moduleN
  |     |-- module1.py
  |     |-- module2.py
  |     |-- ...
  |-- docs
  |     |-- README
  |     |-- LICENSE
  |     |-- ...
  |-- setup.py
```

And my `setyp.py` basically looks like this:

```
# This setup file is to be used with setuptools source distribution
# Run "python setup sdist to deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup( name = "appname",
       ...
       include_package_data = True,
       packages = find_packages(),
       zip_safe = True,
       entry_points = {
           'console_scripts' : 'appname=appname.appname:main'
       }
   )
```

The next step now is to figure out how to install the contents of the docs directory on the users computer.

But right now, I'm thinking about adding --readme, --license, --changes, --sample (and so forth) options to the main script, to display them at run time.